# How can I make sublime appear in the jobs list?

Tags: background-process, job-control, sublime-text

How can I make Sublime Text appear in the jobs list when started from the command line?

For example...

```
$ subl
$ jobs
```

... doesn't show anything.

I want to do this because my prompt is configured to show me the number of jobs I have open in that terminal and it would be convenient to keep track of Sublime as well.